# libMagicWand.so.5 cannot open shared object file?

Tags: emacs, shared-library, 15.04

After update to version Ubuntu 15.04 I have problems when I try to run emacs.

```
emacs: error while loading shared libraries: libMagicWand.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

Meanwhile, when I do: `locate libMagic`

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagick++.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagick++.la
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagick++.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagick++.so.5
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagick++.so.5.0.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagickCore.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagickCore.la
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagickCore.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagickCore.so.5
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagickCore.so.5.0.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagickWand.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagickWand.la
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagickWand.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagickWand.so.5
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libMagickWand.so.5.0.0
```

As you can see `libMagicWand.so.5` at the bottom. So, clearly I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What says: `uname –a`

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall emacs`?

Comment: tried re install, still doesn't work. Same problem

Comment: and `uname -a`?

Comment: uname -a gives me:  3.19.0-15-generic #15 - Ubuntu i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: that are i386 libs

Comment: `libMagicWand.so.5` doesn't exist in Vivid

Comment: what says `apt-cache policy emacs`

Comment: it looks it uses i386 packages. May be this is a problem?

Comment: @NikitaLuparev keep in mind that `libMagicWand.so.5` and `libMagickWand.so.5` are different.  Either you should install the official emacs package or recompile it yourself (since `libMagicWand.so.5` does not actually exist in Vivid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library `libMagickWand.so.5` doesn't exist anymore in Vivid. Install the following library if it is not already installed.

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-6.q16-2
```

If that does not produce the desired result, then proceed here:

---

Either you install the official package of *emacs* or you must recompile it yourself.

With this command you can see, where do you get *emacs* via APT.

```
apt-cache policy emacs
```

Take the URL that is closest to the top. If the URL **DOESN'T** looks like this:

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

**THAN** you can search in the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove the affected line.

---

Alternatively, you can also try to install the libraries from [Utopic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/libmagickwand5) by hand.

Comment: If I compile emacs from source you think it will solve the problem?

Comment: @NikitaLuparev  It depends on which libraries are used in the source code.

Comment: Or you can try a library from Utopic: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=utopic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libmagickwand&searchon=names

Comment: I'm not certain this is the right answer.  It's likely that the package you've indicated (from Utopic) might have been merged with other packages, perhaps the devel headers or otherwise, as `imagemagick` is the source package providing everything.  The [Vivid Source Package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/vivid/imagemagick) actually produces a `libmagickwand` package - `libmagickwand-6.q16-2`, `libmagickwand-6-headers`, and `libmagickwand-6.q16-dev`.  It's possible one of these will do what the OP needs.  (Although consider `magic` is not `magick` and emacs may need revised)

Comment: @ThomasW. I tried to improve my answer.

Comment: I re installed from source. Success, it works. Thank you

Comment: Yes, indeed, recompiling Emacs solves the issue.

Comment: These symbolic links (/ usr / lib64) resolved:
libMagickWand.so.5 -> libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.6.0.0
libMagickCore.so.5 -> libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.6.0.0